# backbone + rails jquery doesn't make a call to error callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I create a method in backbone model for authorization. it selects users correctly, the problem is that upon error a callback for successful authorization is called... i seem to fail to fix this issue...

```
class Notes.Models.User extends Backbone.Model
  url: '/api/account'
  authorize: ->
    jQuery.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/api/sessions.json'
      data:
        email: @get('email')
        password:  @get('password')
    ).success( (response) ->
      alert('success!')
      console.log(response)
    ).error( (response) ->
      alert('error')
    )
```

and rails part

```
def create
    @user = User.authenticate params[:email], params[:password]
    if @user
      create_user_session @user
      respond_with @user, location:'/'
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { error: 'invalid email or password' } }
      end
    end
  end
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ajax success and error callbacks are based upon the HTTP status codes. Otherwise how can it ever know whether the request was successful or not.

So you should return an error http status code like this:

```
format.json { render json: { error: 'invalid email or password' }, status: 401 }
```